# Pythagorean theorem for infinity norm

Tags: linear-algebra, matrix-norms

I am trying to prove or provide a counter-example for the following statement:

If $x$ and $y$ are two complex vectors in $\mathbb{C}^n$ that are perpendicular to each other, i.e., $x^{H} y = 0$ where $H$ denotes Hermitian, then

$\|x\|_{\infty} \leq \|x + y \|_{\infty}$.

This is very easy to prove for norm-2 but I haven't managed to do it for norm-infinity.

Thanks for your help.

Comment: I would call this the triangle inequality rather than the Pythagorean theorem. But it turns out not to be true—try looking geometrically for a counterexample in $\Bbb R^2$.

Comment: Is this really "easy" for the 2-norm?  ||(1,1)||_2  >  ||(1,1) + (-1,-1)||_2.

Comment: @DanAsimov they need to be perpendicular

Comment: I think this is true only when the entries of $x$ are all equal to $c$ or 0 for some $c$